# How to format a javascript date string from year-monthno (2019-1) to month-year (Jan-2019)

Tags: javascript

I have some json data in which i am getting billdates as `2018-9` and `2017-9` i want to convert them as `2018-9` to sept-2018 and `2017-9` to sept-2017

Similarly for all the months like jan,feb,mar,may etc

I have searched on google alot, but didn't find anything until now, i have only found how to convert aug-01-2018 to  `01-08-2018`

- so guys please guide me on, how i could achieve that

I have rendered a HTML table  from that json data, i am commenting the line where i am using bill date

```js
const input = [
  ["Year", "2018-9", "2017-9"],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2018-9", 857],
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2018-9", 169],
  ["KOLAR", "2018-9", 178],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2017-9", 635],
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2017-9", 56],
  ["KOLAR", "2017-9", 90]
]

const merged = input.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  const [city, year, value] = arr;

  if (city === "Year")
    acc[city] = arr
  else {
    acc[city] = acc[city] || [city]
    acc[city].push(value)
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toUTCString()` to get the names and with little string manipulation using split you can get the names of the month

[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

```js
var data = [{
    "amount": 8578579,
    "billdate": "2018-9",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 1693429,
    "billdate": "2018-9",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 1782162,
    "billdate": "2018-9",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 635,
    "billdate": "2017-9",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 56,
    "billdate": "2017-9",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 90,
    "billdate": "2017-9",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
]

data.forEach(e=>{
var a=new Date(e.billdate);
a.setMonth(a.getMonth()+1);
a=a.toUTCString();
var c=a.split(' ');
e.billdate=c[2]+" "+c[3];
})

let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblYoY");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Date";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;//this one is populatingh billdate like 2018-9
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    billdates.forEach(billdate => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.outlet == element && d.billdate == billdate) {

          el = d.amount;

        }
        //console.log(el)
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });

    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
 renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="tblYoY"></table>
</div>
```

```js
const input = [
  ["Year", "2018-9", "2017-9"],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2018-9", 857],
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2018-9", 169],
  ["KOLAR", "2018-9", 178],
  ["JAYANAGAR", "2017-9", 635],
  ["MALLESHWARAM", "2017-9", 56],
  ["KOLAR", "2017-9", 90]
]
var e=input[0]
var a=new Date(e[1]);
a.setMonth(a.getMonth()+1);
a=a.toUTCString();
var c=a.split(' ');
e[1]=c[2]+" "+c[3];
a=new Date(e[2]);
a.setMonth(a.getMonth()+1);
a=a.toUTCString();
c=a.split(' ');
e[2]=c[2]+" "+c[3];


const merged = input.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  const [city, year, value] = arr;

  if (city === "Year")
    acc[city] = arr
  else {
    acc[city] = acc[city] || [city]
    acc[city].push(value)
  }

  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: hey i have an issue to convert the json

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: please check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/y4p26x1g/2/ i am trying to convert with this json

Comment: I'm on my phone. Can you tell it here or update the question if you can

Comment: you want the dates in the JSON to be in words?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189517/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-ellipsis).

Comment: yupp somthing like you are doing here

Comment: check the second snippet i created'

Comment: yupp got that thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to parse your date string, then extract the month in number to format into string.
For example:

```js
var str = "2018-5";
var parts = str.match(/^(\d{1,4})-(\d{1,2})$/);
console.log(parts); // ["2018-5", "2018", "5"]
// example, how to match numeric to month
var months = {"1": "Jan", "2": "Fev", "3": "Mar", "4": "Apr", "5": "Mai"}
var date = months[parts[2]] + "-" + parts[1] // "Mai-2018"
console.log(date)
```

Comment: It's just part of the idea. I mean after extracting the year & the month, now you're able to transform the month in numeric to string value.

Comment: To give you the idea so that you can progress by your self. Btw, just edit the code to show you how it can be done!

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new date:

`const date = new Date(yourStringFromApi);`

And get named months from `toLocaleString`:

`const yourString = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' }); // Mar 2019`

Or your format:

`const yourString = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'short' }) + '-' + date.toLocaleString('en-us', { year: 'numeric' }) // Mar-2019`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using moment.js like so:

```js
let date = moment.utc("2018-11", "YYYY-M").format("MMM-YYYY");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback @ellipsis :)

Comment: OP asked to convert date in words, your code does not do that

Comment: Hey thanks @ellipsis. But didn't he say " i want to convert them as 2018-9 to sept-2018 and 2017-9 to sept-2017".

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

`moment(a.billdate,'YYYY-MM').format('MMM-YYYY')`

```js
var data = [{ "amount": 8578579, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "JAYANAGAR" }, { "amount": 1693429, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM" }, { "amount": 1782162, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "KOLAR" }, { "amount": 635, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "JAYANAGAR" }, { "amount": 56, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM" }, { "amount": 90, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "KOLAR" } ];
data.forEach(a=> a.billdate = moment(a.billdate,'YYYY-MM').format('MMM-YYYY'))
let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblYoY");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Date";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;//this one is populatingh billdate like 2018-9
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    billdates.forEach(billdate => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.outlet == element && d.billdate == billdate) {

          el = d.amount;

        }
        console.log(el)
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });

    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
 renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="tblYoY"></table>
</div>
```

For vanila JS

```js
var m =['','jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','july','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var data = [{ "amount": 8578579, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "JAYANAGAR" }, { "amount": 1693429, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM" }, { "amount": 1782162, "billdate": "2018-9", "outlet": "KOLAR" }, { "amount": 635, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "JAYANAGAR" }, { "amount": 56, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM" }, { "amount": 90, "billdate": "2017-9", "outlet": "KOLAR" } ];

data.forEach(a => {
  var spl = a.billdate.split('-');
  a.billdate = m[Number(spl[1])] + '-' + spl[0];
})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: hey i have an issue

Comment: Why to use a library when same is possible with vanilla JS??

Comment: @viveksingh what a issue?

Comment: @ellipsis its possible check update.But have some simplicity and easy to date validation is there in moment.And single function vanila js is ok.But many no diff type convertion moment is the best joice

Comment: I don't see  and i quote `But many no diff type convertion here`. Just one simple conversion

Comment: @ellipsis .Many no of conversion  just like date to time,time format,utc to normal,normal to utc ,etc

Comment: I got that. But is there any use of them here, in relevance to the question?